# Update multiple records with one form

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am wondering how I can update multiple records individually.

say i have a product model.  and it has price and name for attributes and I only want to update certain attributes

controller

```
class ProductController
  def index
    @products = Products.where(store: store_id)
  end

  def update
     product = Product.find_by(id: params[what goes here]
     product.update(params[how do i find it])
  end
end
```

in my index view i have

```
  Tissue
  <%= form_for @products, url: products_update_path(how do i target the id) do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_area :price, :class => "admin_editor" %>
  <% end %>

  Chair
  <%= form_for @products, url: products_update_path(how do i target the id) do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_area :price, :class => "admin_editor" %>
  <% end %>
```

would the proper way to do it to be.  But I feel like this approach is messy if I have a lot of different products

```
  def index
    @tissue = Product.where(store_id: store_id, name: 'tissue')
    @chair = Product.where(store_id: store_id, name: 'chair')
  end

  def update
     product = Product.find_by(id: params[product_id]
     product.update(params[how do i find it])
  end
```

and in my view do

```
  Chair
  <%= form_for @tissue, url: products_update_path(product_id: @tissue.id) do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_area :price,%>
  <% end %>

  Tissue
  <%= form_for @chair, url: products_update_path(product_id: @chair.id) do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_area :price %>
  <% end %>
```

alternatively, is there a way to do it in a single form_for?

Answer (score 0):

Just a little rails documentation right here:

https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/StrongParameters.html